# meaning differences

Tags: future-tense

Can Somebody explain me the difference between

> Our return date **will be depending** on the cost of airline ticket.
>   Our return date **will depend** on the cost of airline ticket.

Somebody tried to explain it but it is not clear for me

both are in the future but with will be depending you have no idea when  you will  return that is the difference that I have understood . Am I wrong ?

Comment: Please refer to [this link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28234/will-be-doing-vs-will-do). Maybe it helps!

Comment: Idiomatically, future continuous ***will be depending on*** is completely unacceptable, but the explicit future ***will depend on*** is relatively unlikely for most speakers in most contexts. The idiomatic standard is *Our return date **depends** on the cost of [**an / our / the**] airline ticket*. Note that your lack of a "determiner" before ***airline ticket*** is also completely unacceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will start by saying there are several subtly different definitions of the verb **depend**, but for the purpose of this answer I will focus on two of them.

1. (Actually two slightly different definitions, but sufficiently similar in usage for my purposes) to rely upon for support or maintenance; to rely/place trust.
2. To be conditional or contingent on something.

**Will be depending** can only be used in the sense of definition 1, it is at the very least not idiomatic in the sense of definition 2, and may be grammatically incorrect (hopefully someone can point out a reliable resource that says whether it is "against the rules").

The best way I can think of explaining it, is as follows.

- In definition 1, the state of something **remains as it is**, and relies upon something to keep it that way. Therefore the verb "be" is appropriate, because the *state* is dependent.
- In definition 2, the state of something might **change** and the change will be contingent on something. Therefore, "be" is not appropriate, but "change" could be ("Our return date will **change** depending on the cost of airline tickets.") because the *change* (not the state) is dependent.

An example to attempt to explain the subtle difference:

> I **will be depending** on the weather tomorrow. - I am relying on the weather doing what I want it to.
>
> The kick-off time for tomorrow's match **depends** on the weather. - The kick-off time might change, and the condition determining the change is the state of the weather.

In your examples you are saying that the return dates are *contingent* upon the cost of the airline tickets, so you *can't* use "will be depending". As FumbleFingers said, you can use **will depend**, or more idiomatically **depends**. You can do this because the return date has not been decided, so, as well as being dependent in the future, it is also currently dependent upon finding out the costs.

Also, as FumbleFingers said, you need a determiner [an/the/our] before "airline ticket", unless you pluralise "ticket" to "tickets", when you don't *need* a determiner.

Comment: I will be depending on the weather implies that I have planned something before   .  If it rains tomorrow, I will watch the tv , if the weather is hot tomorrow, I will walk. So if it has been planned before  can I also use present continuous ?    Great explaination by the way

Comment: @user5577 Use of "will be depending on" does not imply a change of action, more a reliance on something. E.g. You are going on a boat, but get seasick, you might be depending (rely) on the weather being nice so you are not (quite so) sick. That is different from saying "Whether I get the boat depends on the weather", which means that my decision on whether to get the boat is affected by the weather.